# windows 8 app Back Button causes navigation fail

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I am completely new to developing windows 8 app, and this would be the first project I am working on so bear with me. I have started with a gridview template and attempted to create a class which stores cards and decks. Therefore, each deck is an item in the grid view and by clicking on a deck, it would change to a detail view where the deck's content are shown. Here in lies my problem. When I navigate to my detail view, (which only displays a title thus far) shows a back button, which as far as I know is automatically handled. However, whenever I press the back button to go to my grid view, I am hit with an unhandled exception of

```
Exception = {"Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"}
```

`Message = "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.NavigationFailed was unhandled."`

My detailed view xaml and cs are as follows:

DetailPage.xaml.cs
    using FlashcardBuddy.Data;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

```
// The Item Detail Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234232

namespace FlashcardBuddy
{

    public sealed partial class ItemDetailPage : FlashcardBuddy.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        public ItemDetailPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            // Allow saved page state to override the initial item to display
            if (pageState != null && pageState.ContainsKey("SelectedItem"))
            {
                navigationParameter = pageState["SelectedItem"];
            }

            // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
            var item = SampleDataSource.GetItem((String)navigationParameter);

            this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = item;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = item.Items;
            //this.flipView.SelectedItem = item.Items[0];
        }


        protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            var selectedItem = (Card)this.flipView.SelectedItem;
            pageState["SelectedItem"] = selectedItem.id;
        }
    }
}
```

DetailPage.xaml:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="FlashcardBuddy.ItemDetailPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FlashcardBuddy"
    xmlns:data="using:FlashcardBuddy.Data"
    xmlns:common="using:FlashcardBuddy.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="itemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Items}"
            d:Source="{Binding AllGroups[0].Items[0].Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid
        Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}"
        DataContext="{Binding Group}"
        d:DataContext="{Binding AllGroups[0], Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--
            The remainder of the page is one large FlipView that displays details for
            one item at a time, allowing the user to flip through all items in the chosen
            group
        -->


        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding frontText}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
        </Grid>
        <FlipView x:Name="flipView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1356"/>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The back button respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

My main page's xaml and cs are as follows:

GroupedItemPage.xaml.cs
    using FlashcardBuddy.Data;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Grouped Items Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234231

namespace FlashcardBuddy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A page that displays a grouped collection of items.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class GroupedItemsPage : FlashcardBuddy.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        public GroupedItemsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation.  Any saved state is also
        /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="navigationParameter">The parameter value passed to
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pageState">A dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
        /// session.  This will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
            // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data
            var sampleDataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups((String)navigationParameter);
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = sampleDataGroups;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when an item within a group is clicked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The GridView (or ListView when the application is snapped)
        /// displaying the item clicked.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes the item clicked.</param>
        void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
            // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
            var itemId = ((Deck)e.ClickedItem).id;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
        }

        private void itemGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

GroupedItemPage.xaml

```
    <Page.Resources>

        <!--
            Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a subset
            of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
        -->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="TopItems"
            d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
        <GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,137,40,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDeckTempate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="itemGridView_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,10,0,-10">

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                                <TextBlock
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryGroupStyle}" 
                                    Text="{Binding frontText}" FontFamily="Global User Interface" FontSize="30"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </GridView.GroupStyle>
        </GridView>

        <!-- Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped -->
        <ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Margin="0,-10,0,0"
            Padding="10,0,0,60"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
                                <Button
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding frontText}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        </Grid>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="96,137,10,56"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!--
                    The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                    for the grid displayed in all other view states
                -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

Comment: that's a lot to look at :) can you narrow it down a bit via a debugging session or perhaps post your project on dropbox?

Comment: @JimO'Neil I'm not sure what was wrong in this code, but as I often do, I scrapped the detailpagedview and built it from scratch which solved my problem. Thanks anyways!

Comment: yes indeed, often that's the path of least resistance!  good luck going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just didn't know what I was doing. After a few days of playing around, I ended up building my panel from scratch instead of generating one using a template and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I realized that overriding the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)`, without calling the base implementation was what I did wrong. The `LayoutAwarePage` does some important calculations in there, so missing them will lead to that unhandled exception on back navigation.

I suppose that the same thing applies to the `protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)`.

I know that my solution does not directly applies to you, but this might serve as a reference for others.